# Using Command Prompt to search a particular string in set of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have more then 100 log files in text format. I am using command prompt to search particular string in files using FIND. But i can search only one file at a time. How can i search in all files in one go. Also i want to put result in different text file.

Answer (score 0):

Launch this like `findtext.bat "search string"` and it will create individual *.out files.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.log) do (
find "%~1" < "%%a" > "%%~na.out"
)
```